# Pass data from child action to parent in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, lifecycle, viewbag

When inside a razor view, can you pass data to the view from a child action? IE:

```
@{
   ViewBag.passedData = "";
}

@Html.Action("ChildView","ChildController") // Inside the child action (controller or view) magic happens

@ViewBag.passedData // it's not empty!
```

Note that inside child view, I can read the parent view data using `ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.ViewBag.passedData` but when I write to it, nothing happens.

Turns out that to access the .passedData property, one should use in the parent View:

```
  @ViewContext.ViewBag.passedData   // Has the passed data!
  @ViewBag.passedData // null
```

This will get the ball rolling but if there is a more proper or formal way to do this please reply.

Comment: nothing happens? place break points, step through your code, what DOES it do when it hits that point? the more info you can give the better

Comment: Actually I am going to update with an solution but will still wait for a more formal/proper one (if there is)

Comment: Why are you using ViewBag/ViewData instead of strongly typed view models? What are you trying to achieve? Why are child actions supposed to modify some data used by the parent? I am sure that there are better ways to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You keep saying you want a "proper or formal way."  Using the ViewBag isn't the proper way.  The proper way is to strongly type your views and pass your data around with your models.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737124/does-a-child-action-share-the-same-viewbag-with-its-parents-action

Comment: @Mark The link describes the other way around. Sean, I am trying to create a child view that passes back any dependencies (in css/js files) to the main view so that the main view can arrange/compile them. I am not against using the main model, although that lies in ViewData.Model so it requires access to the ViewData object anyway