# Passing ViewBag objects through public void objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I added the following to my _Layout page:

```
 @Html.Action("ActiveMails", "Home")
```

Which calls the following actions:

```
public void ActiveMails()
{
    var ooo = from s in db.Message
              where (s.SentTo.ToLower() == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToLower())
              && s.Read != "1"
              && s.Active == "1"
              select s;
    ViewBag.UnreadMessages = ooo.Count();
}
```

The problem is that when the page loads it doesn't retain the ViewBag info. Is there any way I can have this code run on every request, but retain the ViewBag information?

Comment: change void  to ActionResult

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737124/does-a-child-action-share-the-same-viewbag-with-its-parents-action

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the return method type to JsonResult? In this case your ViewBag won't change.

```
    public ActionResult ActiveEmails()
    {
        var ooo = from s in db.Message
          where (s.SentTo.ToLower() == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToLower())
          && s.Read != "1"
          && s.Active == "1"
          select s;

        return Json(ooo.Count(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```