# Pass viewbag to partial view from action controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a mvc view with a partial view.There is a ActionResult method in the controller which will return a PartialView. So, I need to pass ViewBag data from that ActionResult method to Partial View.

This is my Controller

```
public class PropertyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        ViewBag.Hello = "Hello";
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

In Index.cshtml View

```
@Html.Partial("Step1")
```

Step1.cshtml partial view

```
@ViewBag.Hello
```

But this is not working. So, what is the correct way to get data from viewbag.
I think I'm following wrong method. Please guide me.

Comment: "Partial view contains ActionResult method in the controller"
what does this mean?

Comment: ActionResult Method returns a PartialView

Comment: Why would you not put this on the model as a property, then pass the property value to the partial view as the partial view's model?

Comment: you could use TempData instead, that works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Child actions follow a different controller/model/view lifecycle than parent actions. As a result they do not share ViewData/ViewBag."

The answer provides an alternate way of passing data.

[Does a child action share the same ViewBag with its "parents" action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737124/does-a-child-action-share-the-same-viewbag-with-its-parents-action)

Answer (score 14):

You can use it as mentioned below :

In your View :

```
@Html.Partial("[ViewName]", (string)ViewBag.Message)
```

And Your partial View :

```
@model String

<b>@Model</b>
```

As Shown Above ViewBag.Message will be passed to the partial view. and in your partial view you can use it as a **@Model**.

**Note :** here type of **ViewBag.Message** is **string**. You can pass any type.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't have to use ViewBag, you can use TempData.  TempData is shared for the whole execution chain.

```
public class PropertyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        TempData["Hello"] = "Hello";
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

In Index.cshtml View

```
@Html.Partial("Step1")
```

Step1.cshtml partial view

```
@TempData["Hello"]
```

Answer (score 10):

Old question but if anyone here to find solution for this question..

You can pass viewbag value to partial with viewdatadictionary.

In your view:

```
@Html.Partial("_Partial", "", new ViewDataDictionary { { "permalink", ViewBag.Permalink } })
```

and in partial view use it like this:

```
ViewData["permalink"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in order to pass ViewBag to partial view from action:

Your controller:

```
public class PropertyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        ViewBag.Hello = "Hello";

        return PartialView("_Partial1", ViewBag.Hello);
    }
}
```

Your view (Index.cshtml):

```
@Html.Action("Step1")
```

Your partial view (_Partial1.cshtml):

```
@ViewBag.Hello
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return PartialView("partialviewname", obj);
```

Comment: Can you provide a more thorough explanation for your answer instead of a single line of code?

Comment: I agree to MattD. Your answer serves no purpose.