# Can we print error message before form begin in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

can we print error message before form start, I am using mvc v4

this is my controller action code
          [HttpGet]

```
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(string aToken)
        {
          aToken = Server.UrlDecode(aToken);

          if (aToken != null)
          {
           .........
           }
          else
          {
      ViewBag.Error = "Sorry, this link is not being recognized as valid. 
          }

    return view();`enter code here`
        }
```

this is my cshtml file

```
    @if (ViewBag.Error != null)

    {
      <p class="text-danger">
        @ViewBag.Error
      </p>
    }
    else
    {
      using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { 
     @class = "form-horizontal ", role = "form" }))
      {

         ........................
      }

    }`enter code here`
```

technicality, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is this solves the problem? Yes. However, it would be more secure just to Redirect user to another page with static text instead. Also, you can use `ModelState` but it will create problems on post actions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we can print error message anywhere we want , according to the place we are providing the error message, it will render the page.

So as per your above code itself , viewbag will print the error message before the form begin, but one small clarification.

> ViewData and TempData require typecasting and null checking whereas
>   ViewBag doesn't need such checking.

It will save you few lines of code as below:

```
 <p class="text-danger">
    @ViewBag.Error
  </p>
  using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { 
 @class = "form-horizontal ", role = "form" }))
  {

     ........................
  }
```

Additional info:http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/36941654-8bd4-4535-9226-ddf47841892f.aspx

Hope above information was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: we can put it anywhere, but does it possible to get it in another partialcontrol?

Comment: Hi Anirudha Gupta , i hope here partialcontrol control means partial view if so yes , We can pass and get it as a model itself. kindly refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20368646/3397630 . thanks